# Angular Function suddenly won't working after Using Jquery Ajax

Tags: php, jquery, html, angularjs, ajax

I'm still new to `php` programming and I'd like to understand why my Angular Function stopped working when I'm using my jquery ajax method post where I update values on my database.

Here is my code on my angular on html:

```
<tfoot ng-app="kembalianApp" ng-controller="kembalianCtrl">
    <tr>
        <th class="has-text-right" colspan="6">TOTAL : </th>
        <th class="has-text-right" ><p ng-model="total" ng-init="total='<?php echo $record2['total'];?>'"><?php echo $total;?></p></th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th class="no-border has-text-right" colspan="6">BAYAR : </th>
        <th style="max-width:100px;padding:0" class="no-border"><input type="text" class="input has-text-right has-text-weight-bold" ng-model="bayar"></th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th class="no-border has-text-right" colspan="6">KEMBALIAN : </th>
        <th class="no-border has-text-right">{{kembalian()}}</th>
    </tr>
</tfoot>
```

and this is how my angular code

```
var app = angular.module('kembalianApp', []);
app.controller('kembalianCtrl', function ($scope) {
    $scope.kembalian = function () {
        if (parseInt($scope.bayar - $scope.total) >= 0) {
            return $scope.result = parseInt($scope.bayar) - parseInt($scope.total);
        } else {
            return $scope.result = '-';
        }
    };
});
```

and this is my Jquery ajax code

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.kurang').on('click', function () {
        var id_pesanan = $(this).data('id_pesanan');
        var id_makanan = $(this).data('id_makanan');
        var jumlah = $(this).data('jumlah');
        jumlah = parseInt(jumlah);
        jumlah = jumlah - 1;
        $.post('assets/ajax/kurangmenu.php', {
            id_makanan: id_makanan,
            id_pesanan: id_pesanan,
            jumlah: jumlah
        }, function (data) {
            $('#containerpesanan').html(data);
        });
    });

    $('.tambah').on('click', function () {
        var id_pesanan = $(this).data('id_pesanan');
        var id_makanan = $(this).data('id_makanan');
        var jumlah = $(this).data('jumlah');
        jumlah = parseInt(jumlah);
        jumlah = jumlah + 1;
        $.post('assets/ajax/kurangmenu.php', {
            id_makanan: id_makanan,
            id_pesanan: id_pesanan,
            jumlah: jumlah
        }, function (data) {
            $('#containerpesanan').html(data);
        });
    });
});
```

I don't get why my angular wont work after I use jquery ajax.

Comment: it's not angular but angularjs, change your tag :)

Comment: Is you jQuery working and AngularJS is not working or nothing is working after adding jQuery code?

Comment: @Alaan : thankyou for your response, i think someone already edited the tag thanks to him.

Comment: @Sayed Mohd Ali : its my Angularjs that seem not working after im pressing the button to change value on my databases using jquery ajax. but the jquery itself is working fine.

And thanks for all your responses, sorry if im making many mistake in here, im still learning by now

Answer (score 0):

Here is the error in your AngularJS code: -

```
<p ng-model="total" ng-init="total='<?php echo $record2['total'];?>'"><?php echo $total;?></p>
```

ng-model is working for two-way binding. p tag is not supported for ng-model. if you want to bind p tag then you can use ng-bind or {{}}.

```
<p ng-bind="total"></p>
```

or

```
<p {{::total}}></p>
```

Comment: okay, thank you for your response Sayed. im really appreciate it, maybe im gonna try it.